# ActionPerformed Method in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have created two JFrames that interact with eachother. The first frame asks for your full name and then when you press next it will transfer your name to the second frame saying "Welcome, whateverYourNameIs." However, I am having the following problems:

1. When I type in the nameField and press next, it overrides the "Welcome" message. "Welcome" should always remain the same followed by your name which obviously should change whenever a different name is entered. How can I fix this problem?
2. Secondly, sometimes in nameWelcome.setText, the nameWelcome has syntax error asking me to create a new variable of this name but I have already created new mathApo(); which is where that variable is located. Why am I seeing this error?

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mathMulti extends JFrame {
    JButton nextButton;
    TextField nameField;
    JLabel fullName;
    JFrame frameOne;
    JPanel panelOne;

    public mathMulti() {

        frameStart();

    }

    public void frameStart() {

        frameOne = new JFrame();
        frameOne.setSize(500, 500);
        frameOne.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panelOne = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panelOne.setBackground(Color.gray);
        frameOne.add(panelOne);

        GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
        fullName = new JLabel("Full Name: ");
        g.insets = new Insets(-390, -195, 0, 0);
        g.gridx = 0;
        g.gridy = 0;
        panelOne.add(fullName, g);

        nameField = new TextField(30);
        g.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        g.gridx = 1;
        g.gridy = 0;
        g.weightx = 0;
        g.weighty = 0;
        g.ipady = 6;
        panelOne.add(nameField, g);

        nextButton = new JButton(" NEXT " + '\u25BA');
        g.insets = new Insets(60, 5, 5, 5);
        g.gridx = 2;
        g.gridy = 5;
        g.weightx = 0;
        g.weighty = 0;

        nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                new mathApo();
                nameWelcome.setText(nameField.getText());
                frameOne.dispose();

            }

        });

        panelOne.add(nextButton, g);

        frameOne.setVisible(true);

    }


    public class mathApo extends JFrame {

        JFrame frameTwo;
        JPanel panelTwo;
        JLabel nameWelcome;

        public mathApo() {

            frameNext();

        }

        public void frameNext() {

            frameTwo = new JFrame();
            frameTwo.setSize(500, 500);
            frameTwo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            panelTwo = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            panelTwo.setBackground(Color.gray);
            frameTwo.add(panelTwo);

            nameWelcome = new JLabel("Welcome, ");
            panelTwo.add(nameWelcome);

            frameTwo.setVisible(true);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1.) When I type in the nameField and press next, it overrides the "Welcome" message. "Welcome" should always remain the same followed by your name which obviously should change whenever a different name is entered. How can I fix this problem?

Calling `setText` on the `JLabel` will replace the existing text with the new text.  A better solution is to have a method in `mathApo` that takes the name and applies it to the label it self, so the caller doesn't need to know "how" the text is formatted - this is a classic example of why you should not give control of your components to other classes

> 2.) Secondly, sometimes in nameWelcome.setText, the nameWelcome has syntax error asking me to create a new variable of this name but I have already created new mathApo(); which is where that variable is located. Why am I seeing this error?

`nameWelcome` in the `ActionListener` does not have any context (or defined variable) either in the `ActionListener` or `frameStart` classes.  You should be using the instance of `mathApo` to reference it (or better yet, a method in `mathApo` that updates it)

## Something different...

I'm going to suggest a slight change in approach...

Rather the relying on two frames, you should use a modal dialog to gather the information you need and then pass the result to the second window, maybe something like...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                RequestInfoPane infoPane = new RequestInfoPane();
                int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, infoPane, "Name", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, 0);
                if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                    WelcomePane welcomePane = new WelcomePane();
                    welcomePane.setFullName(infoPane.getFullName());
                    frame.add();
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class RequestInfoPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel nameLabel;
        private JTextField nameField;

        public RequestInfoPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            nameLabel = new JLabel("Full name: ");
            nameField = new JTextField(20);

            add(nameLabel);
            add(nameField);
        }

        public String getFullName() {
            return nameField.getText();
        }

    }

    public class WelcomePane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel nameLabel;

        public WelcomePane(String fullName) {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            nameLabel = new JLabel("Welcome");
            add(nameLabel);
        }

        public void setFullName(String fullName) {
            nameLabel.setText("Welcome " + fullName);
        }

    }

}
```

Equally, you should consider if a `CardLayout` would also be useful in this situation - see [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you for your swift response. Can you please give me an example of 1 and 2 given the code I have so I can better understand your suggestion for both 1.) and 2.)

Comment: The problem with that is I'd be propagating a bad idea and you wouldn't be learning anything.  Instead, I've updated the example to demonstrate the two points (I've add the `setFullName` method to the `WelcomePane`) - You can also read more about the concept in [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: Okay I understand it now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Everything worked well. Thank you so much. I would also like to know for my knowledge, what if I have two separate textFields such as First Name and Last Name instead of one textField like previously. How would I approach this? Create another method?

Comment: Depends. I might have a the "input" view return a "person" object or have a `getLastName` method.  I would tend to want to keep it simple for the `WelcomePane` and have it take two parameters (`setName(String firstName, String lastName)`, but that's me

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.